# VS code does not detect .NET Core Runtime in Linux Mint

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-code, .net-core, linux-mint

I am trying to use the Oracle Explorer extension in vscode. When I first installed it, vscode popped up [this dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T4tE.png) asking me to install .Net Core Runtime. I followed the link and installed the SDK and runtime (Ubuntu). It seems to have installed correctly. When I type

```
dotnet --info
```

I get this output, which looks okay to me:

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
Version:   6.0.101
Commit:    ef49f6213a

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     linuxmint
 OS Version:  20.3
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         linux-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.101/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 6.0.1
  Commit:  3a25a7f1cc

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.101 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

However, when I re-open vscode I still get the dialog telling me that the Oracle Explorer extension requires the .NET Core Runtime.

I thought it might be a problem with the $PATH variable. This is the output of $PATH:

```
bash: /home/jh/bin:/home/jh/packages/anaconda3/bin:/home/jh/packages/anaconda3/condabin:/home/jh/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/jh/.dotnet/tools: No such file or directory
```

/home/jh/.dotnet/tools does not exist. I tried adding the directories from the "dotnet --info" output to PATH but that didn't work either. I'm in uncharted territory here so that's about as far as I got.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension doesn't currently support the .NET Core Runtime 6.0 (found in an answer [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Oracle.oracledevtools&ssr=false#qna)).

I installed the 5.0 Runtime and everything worked fine.